# Automatic transfer of files from Xubuntu to VLC for iOS through WiFi sharing

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, iphone

I'm using Xubuntu 19.04 and I want to automare the transfer of music from my computer to my phone using the WiFi sharing option that VLC offers (only option I found in order to avoid using iTunes), but I don't really know how to begin, or even in which language should I script.

**How does it work:**
I connect on the same WiFi network, both on my computer and my iPhone, then I enter a specific address on Firefox, and a page like shown below opens. I click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button and then a File explorer opens and I choose which files I want to transfer.

**What I want to do:**
As soon as I download music, which I do frequently, I want to transfer it to my phone automatically through these means.

I'm not asking you to do the job for me, but just some piece of advice or hint on how to do it, using whatever kind of tools. I have some basic knowledge in coding in Python, but I'm certainly not an expert.

[image: VLC WiFi transfer]

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be currently supported by the iOS version of VLC.  You can follow the VideoLAN [bug reporting policy](https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs) which tells you how to submit a feature request to make this possible in the future.